# Natural bijection between join- and meet-irreducibles in modular lattices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-theory, bijective-combinatorics

A [well known property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice#Properties) of finite modular lattices is that they have the same number of join-irreducible and meet-irreducible elements. I was wondering if there exists a natural bijection between these two sets. [Dilworth's original paper](https://doi.org/10.2307/1969639) uses some quite involved computations with Möbius functions to equate the set sizes, other papers [like](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00334848) [these](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(87)90013-6) do prove the existence of certain bijections ("matchings") but these proofs are not particularly constructive and, AFAICT, only define maps up to a certain degree of freedom, so not naturally.

For a distributive lattice one easily obtains a bijection by noting that for any meet-irreducible $m$ there is a unique join-irreducible $j$ such that $m\lor j$ is the element covering $m$. The naive generalization of this to modular lattices does not work but, perhaps, there's something similarly explicit.

Comment: I don’t think there is a canonical bijection at the level of modular lattices. But you might be interested in the “trim” lattices of Thomas. Or even more generally:  https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.08122

Comment: The lattice of subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ is modular, but there is no natural bijection between the lines in $V$ and the hyperplanes in $V$. (Take the ground field to be finite, since you asked for your lattice to be finite.)

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: if $p$ is a nonzero point on a line $L$, let $H$ be the hyperplane of all points $x$ satisfying $p\cdot x=0$. Isn't this a natural bijection? However, this bijection cannot be defined just in terms of the lattice of subspaces. For non-Desarguesian projective planes we don't have this extra structure for defining a bijection between lines and (hyper)planes.

Comment: Hmm... I guess this shows that the answer is indeed negative: a natural bijection would be respected by lattice automorphisms but no bijection between lines and hyperplanes is respected by all linear automorphisms of the space.

Comment: @RichardStanley This bijection involves choosing an inner product on $V$, so it doesn't respect all the symmetries of $V$.

Comment: I'm still somehow vaguely unsatisfied with the proofs of equinumerosity I've seen (like there should be a "deeper"/"more natural" explanation) but, perhaps, that's just because I haven't thought enough about this subject.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: yes, this was foolish of me. But one could ask if there is "reasonable" additional information about the modular lattice $L$ which allows one to define an explicit bijection between meet and join irreducibles. Thus for a subspace lattice, a choice of a basis (which can be defined lattice-theoretically) will do. An obvious example of "unreasonable information" would be a bijection between the meet and join irreducibles. Is a linear ordering of the join-irreducibles (which in the subspace case is more than enough to define an explicit basis) enough information?